# CSS selector: Is there any way to select the last element which has the same class name in the whole html?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul></ul>
... // many ul s here
<ul>
  <li class="list">test1</li>
  <li class="list">test2</li>
  <li class="list">test3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="list">test4</li>
  <li class="list">test5</li>
  <li class="list">test6</li>
</ul>
... // many ul s here
<ul></ul>
```

How do I select the "test6" with CSS selector?

**Important:**

1. Since there may be many ul tags in the page, so I cannot directly write `ul:nth-child(2) > li`
2. Without any js or jQuery functions, CSS only.
3. It's a bit different from other questions. The elements are in the different divs and I want to get the last one which has the `classname="list"`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you cannot ....

Comment: uh, that's so upset!

Comment: if test 6 is the last element in your HTML then it is possible

Comment: I think it could be the last one.

Comment: you will get a bunch of answer because people will consider only the code you posted and won't pay attention to all the requirement, so I advice you to make the code more complex with more element so we can see that it's impossible. You can even provide different output of code if necessary.

Comment: This is not possible without reference to the `ul` element.

Comment: In case people want to know the JS answer, it's `var list = document.querySelectorAll['li.list']; list = list[list.length-1];`

Answer (score 1):

You could combine last-of-type with last-child

```css
ul:last-of-type .list:last-child  {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">test1</li>
  <li class="list">test2</li>
  <li class="list">test3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="list">test4</li>
  <li class="list">test5</li>
  <li class="list">test6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Btw, if the ul is not the last one, what should i do?

Comment: Can u add a class on the ul?

Comment: Unfortunately.I can't.

Comment: You have to have some kind of identifier somewhere :) otherwise it's not possible. For example you could split everything in header,content & footer. This way you could say last item in content. But otherwise there is no way :)

Comment: If the `ul`s are next to each other, you can use `nth-of-type(2)` instead of `last-of-type`, in this example at least

Comment: @Marc I guess the data is dynamic

Comment: Yeah it's probably impossible then

Comment: Yes, the data is dynamic, and I only know it's the last element with the class name.

Comment: Hopefully CSS selector can be good as jQuery or JavaScript.Feelsbadman

Answer (score -1):

It's possible only if test6 is the last element in the HTML

Try this

```css
ul:last-child li.list:last-child{
  color:green;
}
```

Working codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmRqpg

Comment: Btw, if the ul is not the last one, what should i do?

Comment: `<ul>
  <li class="list">test1</li>
  <li class="list">test2</li>
  <li class="list">test3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="list">test4</li>
  <li class="list">test5</li>
  <li class="list">test6</li>
</ul><ul>
  <li>test7</li>
  <li>test8</li>
  <li>test9</li>
</ul>` like this.

Comment: Then you can't do it

Comment: Alright, thank you so much.

Comment: Consider using javascript

Comment: Yes, I should. But it may be a little weird in the React project.

Comment: But there's an alternate way i.e.., applying styles except for the last element

Answer (score -4):

`ul:last-of-type .list:last-of-type {
    background: #ff0000;
}`

Comment: Btw, if the ul is not the last one, what should i do?

Comment: add id attribute to it, so it can be easily found and be unique Optionally, instead of `ul:last-of-type` use `ul:nth-child(1)` where 1 is the ul number of all uls